# trying to get imei number in android - phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I tried in getting IMEI number in android after looking into some blogs.

Below is my Native Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{

    private static String imei;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.init();
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei=tm.getDeviceId();
        LOG.d("kp","hello");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    static public String getIMEI(){
        return imei;
    }


}
```

and calling getIMEI function in app.js file created by ionic framework.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
  var imei = window.MainActivity.getIMEI();
    alert("hi "+imei);
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Alert itself is not coming.

if I replace below

```
var imei = window.MainActivity.getIMEI();
    alert("hi "+imei);
```

with

```
alert("Hi");
```

Alert is coming as expected but it is breaking when I add     `var imei = window.MainActivity.getIMEI();`

can someone help what I am missing to get IMEI number.

Comment: Define _"it is breaking"_. Also, have you made sure that you obtained a valid string in `onCreate` by trying to print it there?

Comment: it is breaking means nothing is coming (expectation is alert). basically i am trying this in emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally. 
appview has method to get webview.
Webview has method to set javainterface which allows to call from JavaScript.